# A word for "the quality of being temperamental" i.e. *temperamentalness*

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

*Temperamentalness* not being a word in the English language as such, what quality might you say someone who is temperamental possesses?  Temperamentality has a bit of a "made up" ring to it too.

Comment: Google Books claims 283 written instances of [*temperamentalness*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Temperamentalness%22), but that must be set against 1140 instances of [*temperamentality*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Temperamentality%22) (and *neither* are listed in the full subscription-only OED). They do list *trivialness* and *irritableness* though (defined as a ***rare*** alternatives to *triviality, irritability*). But I wouldn't use "in a dictionary" as the final word on whether something's a word or not. Imho they're both regularly-formed, hence "acceptable".

Comment: *Excitability, capriciousness, irritability, irascibility, touchiness, moodiness, oversensitivity,*...

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. Here, looking up synonyms for 'temperamental' is an obvious starting place.

Answer (score 2):

A close synonym for tempramental is *volatile*. *[Volatility](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/volatility)* includes the definition:

> 3. changeable; mercurial; flighty:
>      a volatile disposition.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could get by with *[moody](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/moody)*:

> **moody**
>   *adj*
>   1. Given to frequent changes of mood; temperamental.
>   2. Subject to periods of depression; sulky.
>   3. Expressive of a mood, especially a sullen or gloomy mood: *a moody silence*.

Noun form: *moodiness*. [Thanks @DanBron!]

Comment: He wants a noun. So *moodi**ness***.

Comment: I normally understand *temperamental* to mean *prone to erratic or unpredictable changes* (in mood *or* performance, which is why you might say a piece of electronic equipment is temperamental if it doesn't always work as expected). To me, *moody/moodiness* always implies sullenness/gloom, whereas *temperamental* can apply to both aspects of, say, manic depression (or more precisely, to the tendency to switch unpredictably between the two modes/moods).

Answer (score 0):

> volatility, instability, inconstancy, variability, inconsistency, unpredictability, capriciousness, eccentricity, changeableness, moodiness

Source: Google dictionary, and Merriam Webster online dictionary

> (According to this Google blog post which was repeated by searchenginewatch, the Oxford Pocket English Dictionary is used, and the statistics on word usage come from their N-gram tool, which is now publicly available.)
>
> https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60249/where-does-google-get-its-dictionary-data

Comment: A citation to "Google dictionary" is [not accepted as a valid reference](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7053/55623) for supporting one's answer, [for a variety of important reasons](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11101/55623). Best practice is to find the reference work Google is passing through, and [cite it directly](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11058/55623).

Comment: There needs to be a link to a relevant supporting reference, and some proof that a list is not just one listing the modern replacements for Rudolph and company or the 10 Dwarfs.